# When does homology preserve inverse limits of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Let $... \to G_3 \to G_2 \to G_1$ be an inverse system of abelian groups and $G$ the limit of the system. By a theorem of Goerss the integral homology of the Eilenberg-MacLane space $K(G,n)$ for $n >0$ is computed as $H_*(K(G,n)) = lim_{i> 0} H_*(K(G_i,n))$ if the inverse system $... \to G_3 \to G_2 \to G_1$ is Mittag-Leffler. Here the limit is taken in the category of graded coalgebras.
Under which conditions agrees this limit with the limit of graded abelian groups?
Does the situation gets easier when the inverse system is an inverse system of vector-spaces?